# How to check if a variable is defined for a page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a Wordpress theme (Energy by artstudioworks) I bought that included a nice slider (Revolution Slider by Theme Punch) with it.  The theme framework references the slider in the header loop for every page and post to see what you selected in the drop down menu.

I use another plugin (dsIDXpress by Diverse Solutions) that creates posts dynamically from an XML feed and thus the slider variable is never created or defined.

The theme author checks for the slider in the header loop with an if-else, however, since the variable is not present on these pages, the slider displays with an error.  The relevant code is:

```
    <?php
global $options_data;
global $wp_query;
if(isset($wp_query->queried_object->ID)) {$postid=$wp_query->queried_object->ID;} 
else {$postid='';}


if (get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != '' 
&& get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != '0' 
&& get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != 'No Slider') 
{ 
    if(class_exists('RevSlider'))
{ putRevSlider(get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true )); }

 } else { 
 if ( $options_data['select_blogtitlebar'] == 'Image' ) { ?>
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What line is throwing the error, and what error is it throwing?  Checking if a variable is defined is done with `isset()` normally

Comment: `code`( if (get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != '' 
&& get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != '0' 
&& get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != 'No Slider'))

pages that were dynamically created have sliders.  so would:

`code`( if (get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != '' 
&& get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != '0' 
&& get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ) != 'No Slider' && isset( 'energy_revolutionslider' ) != 'false' ))

be the answer? I'm not a php guy..

Comment: So that's the line, what error is it giving? Verbatim please.

Comment: I'm getting a slider on all the dynamic pages.  the slider reads "Revolution Slider Error: Slider with alias not found. 

Maybe you mean: 'test'"

test is a test slider I gave it.. It thinks there should be a variable in there that is not there.

Comment: I would guess The slider has not been set when creating the page, hence `get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true )); ` returns a non-existing slider. Add a conditional check to make sure `get_post_meta( $postid, 'energy_revolutionslider', true ));` returns a value before calling the slider, and only call the slider if it is set. Then you will get no errors.